# Optional fields in renderFieldset

Tags: component, custom-component, jform, joomla-4.x

I'm updating a component of mine to use the `renderFieldset` method and remove some unnecessary code in the form template files. However, some of my fields show / hide based on other preferences in the component. Is there a way to add any kind of show / hide logic when using the `renderFieldset` method? Or would I have to manually parse the form and output the logic inline as I'm doing currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Form API `setFieldAttribute()` method to set the attribute of a field based on your config params. Then when you do `renderFieldset()` - which basically just does a `renderField()` for each of the fields in the fieldset - the revised field attribute will be taken into account when that field is rendered.

So what you probably want to do is something like

```
$form = getForm(...);
if ("myfield1" should be hidden)
{
    $form->setFieldAttribute("myfield1", "type", "hidden");
}
```

where "myfield1" is the name of the field you want to hide. Then do, as normal:

```
$form->renderFieldset("xxx");
```